# Compressing XML File

Tags: c#, .net

All,

I have a requirement to Compress an XML file. At the moment I am using C# and the gzip algorithm in the .NET Classes. I does compress it but not at the rate I would like to.
For example a 12MB file was compressed to a little less than 4MB.

Is there any other way to compress it more than that? Speed of compression / decompression is not very important.

Thanks,
M

Comment: That's still 1/3, are you compressing the XML piecemeal or as a whole?

Comment: Note that the compression rate that you get also depends strongly on the input data. If you have a document that contains one large base-64 blob which possibly is already compressed (e.g. JPEG) you won't be able to shrink your document very much.

Answer (score 2):

ZIP compression is well suited for compressing XML data. In .NET you best rely on third party libraries:

- [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/)
- [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/)

Answer (score 0):

You may [try 7zip](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/064b41e4-60bc-4d35-9136-368603bcc27a/7zip-lzma-inmemory-com.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

[7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) has an [SDK](http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html).

Use the client version of 7-zip to try different compression settings to find the one with best compression for your particular data set.

Answer (score 0):

[This website](http://cs.fit.edu/~mmahoney/compression/text.html) compared different compression libraries against large amount of text data. 7-zip is also included. I hope that this helps you to choose correct library that matches your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `System.IO.Packaging.ZipPackage` in `WindowsBase`. It's the .NET framework code behind the DOCX & XLSX file formats and these are more or less zipped XML files. You can zip multiple files of any format together, not just XML.